# В каком файле и строке ошибка?

Tags: git, git-conflict

Как мне понять в каком файле и строке ошибка?
Проблема в том, что я пытался проект залить на гит и у меня был конфликт, который я благополучно проигнорировал и теперь у меня в файле где-то комментарий "<<<<<<< HEAD", а найти я его не могу. [image: Ошибка]

Самое интересно, что при повторном запуске программы, эта ошибка не высвечивается.

[Сам проект](https://github.com/Fa4stik/Lab8.2)

Comment: А прямо поиском по всем файла проекта пробовали искать?

Comment: Да, я уже по несколько раз все файлы осмотрел никак найти не могу

Comment: Прямо по всем-всем файлам искали? Попробуйте почистить проект и полностью пересобрать, если есть такая опция.

Comment: Похоже на остатки неразрешенного гит/свн конфликта .. Находите и разрешайте

Comment: Плохо искали - в каталоге `Lab8.2\obj\Debug\ ` в файлах `MainWindow.g.i.cs` и `PIS8_2.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt` есть эти строки. `Clean project` и `Rebuild project` должно помочь. И на всякий случай перезапустите сначала вашу `IDE`. Я помню у меня в `VS` были иногда похожие приколы.

Comment: И добавьте метку языка программирования и конкретной `IDE`, которую вы используете

Comment: @Kromster Скорее это глюки с кэшированием у `IDE`. В текущих исходниках проекта уже такого нет, но `IDE` запомнила и глючит.

Comment: @CrazyElf или был конфликт, IDE файлы обновила. Конфликт разрулили, а в IDE не обновили, а потом при сохранении конфликт "вернулся".

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо огромное!!! Я 3 дня мучался с этой ошибкой, файлы поправил теперь всё запускается без проблем. Цены просто вам нет!

Comment: А с вопросом что теперь делать?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, вопрос решён

Comment: Так чистка помогла или вы руками файлы "чинили"? Просто файлы в `obj` по идее должны перезаписываться при `Rebuild`-е. Хотя если это глюк клиента `git`-а, то может и файлы нужно править. В общем, хорошо было бы, если бы вы сами оформили ответ - что вы сделали, что помогло починить.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил правкой двух файлов: MainWindow.g.i.cs и PIS8_2.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt, где соответственно и был комментарий "<<<<<<< HEAD". Также пересобрал проект. Отдельная благодарность @CrazyElf